# Binding ASP ListView and Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a dropdownlist of my item types and a listview of my all items and 2 datasources that i bind them to each one and when i choose each types from drop down list it filter the items from list view but i don't know how to show all the list items? it only filters the data by type.
how can i add "Show All" item to drop down list while it reads the data from datasource.

List view Data source:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [BookTbl] WHERE ([TypeId] = @TypeId)">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="BookListddl" Name="TypeId" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Drop Down List Data Source:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [BookTypeTbl]">
```

Answer (score 0):

I Suppose You have a dropdownlist name ddl and listview as lvMyItems.

```
           Protected void Page_Load(Object sender,EventArgs e)
                {
                if (this.IsPostBack)
                 {
                    string command = SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand; // added just for debug purpose
                    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [BookTypeTbl]";
                    SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
                    ddl.DataBind();

        ddl.Items.Insert(0,"Show All");

                  }
            }
        Protected void ddl_SelectedIndexchanged(Object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
    if(ddl.SelectedValue > 0)
    {
           string command = SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand; 
                    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [BookTbl] WHERE ([TypeId] = '"+ddl.SelectedValue+"'";

         SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
        }
    else
    {
      string command = SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand; 
                    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [BookTbl] ";

         SqlDataSource1.DataBind();

//rebind your listview here
    }
    }
```